# Translating Arduino to ChibiOS

Tags: arduino, atmega, chibios

I'm trying to implement "one wire" for ChibiOS, running on atmega1280 (Arduino board). I am mostly copy/pasting from the arduino implementation (which works fine):

```c
uint8_t OneWire::reset(void)
{
    IO_REG_TYPE mask = bitmask;
    volatile IO_REG_TYPE *reg IO_REG_ASM = baseReg;
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t retries = 125;

    noInterrupts();
    DIRECT_MODE_INPUT(reg, mask);
    interrupts();
    // wait until the wire is high... just in case
    do {
            if (--retries == 0) return 0;
            delayMicroseconds(2);
    } while ( !DIRECT_READ(reg, mask));

    noInterrupts();
    DIRECT_WRITE_LOW(reg, mask);
    DIRECT_MODE_OUTPUT(reg, mask);  // drive output low
    interrupts();
    delayMicroseconds(480);
    noInterrupts();
    DIRECT_MODE_INPUT(reg, mask);   // allow it to float
    delayMicroseconds(70);
    r = !DIRECT_READ(reg, mask);
    interrupts();
    delayMicroseconds(410);
    return r;
}
```

What I wrote for the ChibiOS implementation of the "reset" function is the following:

```c
uint8_t OneWire::reset(void)
{
    palSetPadMode((ioportid_t)IOPORT2, 3, PAL_MODE_INPUT);

    // Wait until the wire is high.
    uint8_t retries = 125;
    do {
        if (--retries == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        chThdSleepMicroseconds(2);
    } while (palReadPad(IOPORT2, 3) == PAL_LOW);

    palSetPadMode((ioportid_t)IOPORT2, 3, PAL_MODE_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL);
    palWritePad(IOPORT2, 3, PAL_LOW); // drive output low
    chThdSleepMicroseconds(480);

    palSetPadMode((ioportid_t)IOPORT2, 3, PAL_MODE_INPUT);
    chThdSleepMicroseconds(70);
    uint8_t result = (palReadPad(IOPORT2, 3) == PAL_LOW);
    chThdSleepMicroseconds(410);

    return result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you expect and what is the result?

Comment: I figured out what is the problem with the help of the author of ChibiOS (on the http://chibios.org/ forum). The problem was that chThdSleepMicroseconds cannot achieve a microsecond delay. It is rounded to the nearest clock tick which, in my case, was 1 KHz, hence one millisecond. One needs to use either busy looping or a high-precision timer to achieve microsecond delayd.